# How to intercept and preproccess arguments with decorators?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators

I have a situation where I am writing many functions of the form

```
def func(arg):
    arg=pre_process(arg)
    return do_work(arg)
```

I want to make it possible to do this preprocessing of arg in an easier way. I have tried to use decorators like in the following example

```
from typing import Callable


def super_decorator(arg_name: str, pre_fn: Callable) -> Callable:
    def decorator(fn):
        def inner(*args, **kwargs):
            assert arg_name in kwargs.keys()
            kwargs[arg_name] = pre_fn(arg_name)
            return fn(*args, **kwargs)

        return inner

    return decorator



#example

def pre_processor(x):
    return "pre-processed"


@super_decorator("arg1", pre_processor)
def func(*, arg1=None):
    return arg1


print(func(arg1="hello world"))
```

Using this technique I get the correct output

```
pre-processed
```

However this is a bit hacky, and I have to force key-word arguments. Is there a better way?

Comment: What do you mean that you have to force keyword arguments?

Comment: You only need keyword arguments if the argument to preprocess isn't fixed to be the first (or second, etc) positional parameter.

Comment: Good point, I guess instead of using key word arguments you pass the index(es) of arguments together with the pre-processor function(s) to the outer-most decorator and do it that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The decorator you wrote is far more general than your first example requires. You could simply write

```
def compose(preprocessor):
    def decorator(f):
        def inner(arg):
            return f(preprocessor(arg))
        return inner
    return decorator


@compose(pre_processor)
def func(arg):
    return do_work(arg)
```

So in order to decide whether your `super_decorator` is well designed, you need to more precisely define the problem it is trying to solve.

---

I used the name `compose` because your superdecorator is just the curried form of a composition operator. If you know any Haskell, you would simply write

```
func = do_work . pre_processor
```

Answer (score 1):

One pattern I've seen is to use references to functions as annotations on the arguments you want those functions applied to

```
from typing import Callable
from functools import wraps
from inspect import signature
from collections import OrderedDict


def use_annotations(func):
    sig = signature(func)
    @wraps(func)
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        bound = sig.bind(*args, **kwargs)
        bound.apply_defaults()
        bound.arguments = OrderedDict(
            (param, sig.parameters[param].annotation(value))
            if isinstance(sig.parameters[param].annotation, Callable)
            else (param, value)
            for param, value in bound.arguments.items()
        )
        return func(*bound.args, **bound.kwargs)
    return inner


def pre_processor(x):
    return "pre-processed"


@use_annotations
def func(*, arg1: pre_processor=None):
    return arg1


print(func(arg1="hello world"))
```

This probably won't play nicely with most tools that expect you to be using annotations for type hinting.

Comment: Haven't had to use signature before, that's pretty spiffy

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a better way?

No, I don't believe so.

Code review time. Ok, having reviewed your code, I give it thumbs up.
LGTM. Ship it!

Sorry. I can see why you would feel that there's sort of a lot of ceremony
going on in this code, but what you wrote is the most natural way to express it.
Kudos for the annotations, and for using `typing`.